# Wildcard-like filtering for S3 put events using Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Here's a snippet of my YAML file:

```
functions:
  users:
    handler: incoming.handler
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: mybucket
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: incoming/
            - suffix: .zip
```

This will match for objects created named `incoming/*.zip`.

I want to add another key with date time for easy partitioning using Athena. So the full "path" in S3 will be something like this:

```
incoming/date=<timestamp>/<filename>.zip
```

Using the rules defined above do not seem to match with the result that the function does not fire.

How do I match using this technique?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm afk at the moment I take it incoming/* doesn't work?

Comment: If not how about you include a meta.json with each file perhaps?

Comment: OR just watch the root folder for new object(which will be a folder) then check inside the new folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot get this to work using pure Serverless framework functionality, you could try an alternative approach:

1. Setup the bucket so that SNS notification is triggered on object creation. You can then hook up your Serverless lambda to trigger from SNS.

   See the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html
2. Then use SNS filtering to look for `.zip` (or whatever else you want to use) to trigger only on the files you are interested in: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/sns/

good luck!